# Use Samsung Comic Fun Filter from Samsung in SDK

Tags: android, filter, camera, samsung-mobile, action-filter

I'm looking for a possibility to use the Samsung Comic Fun Filter in my Android App. Is there a possibility to do this? Or is this exclusive for the Samsung apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Samsung provides an API for that. Image filters are included in the S-Pen SDK.

You can download the S-Pen SDK from here:
http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk

Tutorials on using image filters using the S-Pen SDK are available here:
http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-2-5-Tutorial#h7